# How do I convert μm^2 to meters^2?

Tags: meter, metric-system

From my text, I read:

```
Estimated soma area, in μm^2, is from 1073 to 2400 and estimated total
somadendritic area is from 3914 to 11,158 μm^2.
```

How do I convert μm^2 to meters^2?

Comment: I don't understand -- "u' is the unit of atomic mass. Do you mean Angstroms? Micrometers? In any event -- just multiply by the square of the relevant linear conversion factor.

Comment: Sorry,  but I'm still a little confused how to get to cm^2, from u^2. Here is the full paragraph from the article.                                                 "Estimated soma area, in u2, is from 1073 to 2400 and estimated total
somadendritic area is from 3914 to 11,158 u2. Capacitance can be
estimated from area using the 1 uF per square cm rule, and this
gives a mean of 55 pF with a most likely value of 39 pF. Using instead
the time constants and input resistances gives a higher mean of
89.5 pF.

Comment: I thought you wanted m^2. Where did cm^2 come from?

Comment: cm^2 or m^2, doesn't matter- I just don't understand the u^2 notation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about basic arithmetic, and has nothing at all to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

1 μm = 10^-6 m

Hence

1 μm = 10^-4 cm

so

1 μm^2 = 10^-8 cm^2

Comment: I figured that μm^2 = micrometer. Thank you, I just didn't realize u^2 is the symbol for micrometers.